# Друпал 8 очень долго открываются страницы

Tags: php, drupal

Есть windows 10, xampp последний со всем вытекающими, Drupal 8. Компьютер не самый древний. Очень долго открывается сайт с коробки и очень долгий переход ( порядка 20+сек) страницам. Есть идеи как ускорить или что сделать?

Comment: если CMS новый возможно проблема в локальном сервере.... в браузере откройте консоль (F 12) и вкладку Nertwork, после перезагрузите страницу сайта и посмотрите в консоли что тормозит сайт

Comment: @Arsen Стартовая страница рендорится 2+мин в основном больше времени ajax

Comment: 2 мин - это катастрофа ))  средняя скорость загрузки сайта должно быть 3-6 сек.  Если вы используете готовый шаблон, возможно там могут быть JS ошибки при работе AJAX, что то не подгружается. В первую очередь вам надо или переустановить локальный сервер, или установить сайт на реальны хостинг и посмотреть что будет. Если изменений не будет, значит проблема в шаблоне и необходимо по шагам делать проверку и смотреть по кускам загружаемый код в шаблоне

Comment: @Arsen в том то и дело что друпал с коробки, грешу на фрагментацию диска или каких то его настроек, или что php в режиме cgi работает

Comment: ну вот, чтобы проблему с железом проверить надо сделать то что я описал выше

Comment: @Arsen походу проблема была в софте, поставил опенсерв и выбрал по максимум версии х64 и все в принципе летает, а может и дефрагментация дала эффект, в общем комплекс мер позволил побороть тормоза)

Comment: думаю проблема была именно в сервере, так часто бывает ))

Comment: @Arsen ставил на х32 убунту не особо прирост был по скорости